# Nginx: disconnect when client sends chunked body exceeding desired size

Tags: nginx, chunked

In nginx there is the following directive `client_max_body_size`:

> Sets the maximum allowed size of the client request body, specified in
>   the “Content-Length” request header field. If the size in a request
>   exceeds the configured value, the 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error
>   is returned to the client.

As it says, this is used when Content-Length is provided in the request. I am using nginx as reverse proxy. Unfortunately, my nodejs implementation for a particular URI requires a POST body to be provided with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` -- it breaks otherwise. I still need to limit the accepted body size to prevent DoS. I'd like nginx to close the connection if too many bytes have been sent in the body.

Does nginx have *that* functionality? Or would I be better off implementing that on the nodejs server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, `client_max_body_size` actually does apply to `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` requests. I found this out during testing. The documentation just doesn't mention this.